# access git repository from server in DMZ, accessed through VPN tunnel

Tags: vpn, git, ssh-tunnel, dmz

My laptop `mylaptop` has access to a git repo `mygitrepo.com`.
From `mylaptop` I can access a web server in a DMZ `dmzserver` through a VPN tunnel.

Of course, `dmzserver` cannot directly access `mygitrepo.com`.
How can I make the `dmzserver` do `git clone/pull` from `mygitrepo.com` through the VPN tunnel (via `mylaptop`)?

Comment: How does `mylaptop` have access to `mygitrepo.com`, is it internally hosted, how is the DNS setup?  Also, is `mygitrepo.com` require specific authentication?

Comment: `mygitrepo` is a gitlab private repo, so it is externally hosted, but `mylaptop` is not in the DMZ so has full internet access.